# SQL Server 2012 error - Lock Request Timeout exceeded

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

1. I get an error 'lock request time out exceeded' when shrink log file and Backup database
2. I know when this error will come. Some transaction should be locking the table.

   **But I need to know how to    find that?**

Thanks

Comment: The quick answer is to work with `sp_lock`, or it's basis, system table `master.dbo.syslockinfo`. Actually dredging useful information from them can be tricky, hopefully someone can post a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use DMVs to find out what locks are being held and by whom.

```
SELECT L.resource_type, L.request_mode, L.request_type, L.request_status, L.request_session_id, S.[host_name], S.[program_name], s.login_name
    FROM sys.dm_tran_locks AS L
        INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS S
            ON S.session_id = L.request_session_id
    WHERE resource_database_id = DB_ID(N'msdb');
```

[image]

See Books Online > sys.dm_tran_locks (Transact-SQL): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx

Books Online > sys.dm_exec_sessions (Transact-SQL): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176013.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> I get an error 'lock request time out exceeded' when shrink log file and Backup 
>   database

I be this is wrong you get it for the logfile shrink, NOT the backup. And a logfile shrink is NOT SOMETHING YOU SHOULD DO TO START WITH. Not as part of regular maintenance.

Shrinking anything regularly in SQL Server is a sign of bad planning or administrator incompetence. Preallocate sensible amounts, live with them. Particularly with a logfile, the growth should be planned to have sensible virtual log file sizes.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.08.database.aspx

explains the logic behind them.

So, your question is barking the wrong tree.